# Unable to connect raspberry pi Minecraft server

Tags: raspbian, server, minecraft

I am new to Linux and I am trying to set up Minecraft on a raspberry pi 4 using raspberian full. I think that I set up the server correctly but I am unable to connect to the locally or remotely. I can see Java listing on port 25565

Answer (score 0):

You can always open terminal and type "ifconfig". Once you entered that, look at "wlan0", and then find "inet" under "flags". Your local IP address should be shown after "inet: ".

Additionally, I have a video on how to connect locally and remotely and how to set up a server (Pi 4).

[Local connection](https://youtu.be/eSYgIOaZZnU)

[Remote connection](https://youtu.be/p6f6e5ah8Vk)

[Server setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBX-90NcAJo&t=2s)